# how to create empty database in ce and display it with datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagrid, compiler-errors, sql-server-ce

so, my code

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }
        SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
        en.CreateDatabase();

        SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Open();
        string sql = "create table EnergyMain(id int not null, date datetime not null, totalamount float)";
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCeCommand tbltodgv = new SqlCeCommand("EnergyMain", cn);
        tbltodgv.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
        SqlCeResultSet rs = tbltodgv.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable | ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
        dgvMain.DataSource = rs;

        cn.Close();
```

this code creates simple null database with one empty table. when i press button on the form it's create it. but when i press it second time it writes error

```
Invalid attempt to call method Updatable when SqlResultSet is closed.
```

how can i create database as many times as i want

Comment: may be smb can help me to create empty 'SqlCeResultSet'

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the datagridview to the resultset, do not close the underlying connection, so remove cn.Close()

Comment: in this way connection is busy and it can't open it again. so another error occurs.

Comment: breakes on this string File.Delete(fileName)

Comment: You must close the connection before you delete the file (if it is Open)